# iOS Map with place search option

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, mapkit, foursquare

I would like to get suggestions about how to integrate place search functionality in iPhone app.
Following are the possible solutions which I have found while searching.

1.**Google Places Api + iOS Mapkit**

Problem: According to new Google Policy we can not use Google Apis with another map frameworks.

2.**Google Places Api + Google Map iOs SDK**

Problem: I have registered for Google Map iOs SDK Api key but yet i haven't received api key.

3.**Four Square Api + iOS Mapkit**

Problem: Not sure about validity of data as the search options includes very sensitive data like police stations, hospitals.

4.**Google Map Javascript Api**

Problem: not provide native look.

I would like to use Google Places Api but for that i need to get Google iOS SDK api key.

Feel Free to Give any Suggestions or other options.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CLGeocoder` for basic search functionality. Specifically, you can use `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:` and it's related `geocodeAddressString:inRegion` methods. This is built into iOS, works with both iOS 5 and 6 maps versions, and allows for basic search (street, business name, etc).

I would recommend you see if it is suitable for your purpose - if not then you can look at other options, but best to at least consider the built in functionality first.

Comment: thanks for your answer i will check, and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Hi is it possible with the a CLGeocoder to get list of hospitals in particular area, like in app user want to get all hospitals in california.

Comment: No - for that you'd want to use something like the Foursquare API.

Comment: hello lxt, can i search nearest locations from my current location using CLGeocoder ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Facebook Places API. It integrates easily with MapKit and there's a very good tutorial for it.

Follow these steps to install the SDK
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

And here's the tutorial
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Just use MKLocalSearch ...  crude example here: http://phpadvocate.com/blog/2013/01/ios-6-1-simple-example-using-mklocalsearch/